# How can I control how many features my algorithm requires for a certain accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection

I generate datapoints with 25 features using a Monte Carlo algorithm. Basically I have two spheres (each representing one label) and determine how deeply they intersect each other by adapting their centres and radians. I combine them for the dataset. Like this:

```
centre1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4]                # length is 25
centre2 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]
radian1 = 15
radian2 = 15
```

A picture of feature 1 plotted over feature 2 would look like this (the dataset includes both clouds).
[image: Feature 1 over 2]

I use a random forest from Sk-learn to separate these clouds from each other.
Right now the algorithm requires around 5 features to reach its best accuracy (hence the picture; please neglect the fact that is shows over 25 features).

[image: num of features over accuracy]

Bringing the spheres centers closer together does not result in a change in the minimum of features needed for peak accuracy. Moreover if they intersect too deeply the eventual accuracy will decrease but still be reached with just 5 features.

How can get this threshold up to around 15 features? What else has an influence on the number of features required for a random forest?

I also asked this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399656/what-does-the-number-of-features-needed-for-machine-learning-rely-on), but could not get it answered.

Comment: Why do you want to increase the number of features needed? If at most you need five features, i.e. if those five features contain enough information to separate your two classes, why do you *want* to add more features beyond those? And it looks like you get comparable accuracy at 15 features, so you could just use 15, but again, why?

Comment: This might be because your decision tree doesn't consider some features as important. I would consider [visualizing your decision tree](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-a-decision-tree-from-a-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-38ad2d75f21c) to help you figure out what is happening.